# Does Drill work with Ignite In-memory DB?

Tags: ignite, apache-drill

[https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/#using-the-rdbms-storage-plugin][1]

This link says Drill can work with any JDBC-compliant RDBMS. Is it known to work with Apache Ignite In-memory DB?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should be compliant with Ignite. Ignite has full JDBC [support](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/JDBC/jdbc-driver). It also worth mentioning that Drill directly supports H2 as a dialect. Ignite has the same dialect as H2, it uses H2 internally for query parsing.